# GridView onclick not responding with EditText

Tags: android, gridview

I want a `Gridview` with image and `EditText`. I want to show image in fullscreen on click and select that `Gridview` item to delete on long click.But the `GridView` events `OnItemLongClickListener()` and `OnItemClickListener()` are not responding with `EditText`, though they work when `Edittext` `android:focusable="false"` is set. I have tried many different solutions but none of them are working. here is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
     android:numColumns="2"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:columnWidth="100dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/grid"
     />
   </LinearLayout>
```

grid_single.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/lin"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
</ImageView>

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/grid_text"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="150dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main_activity.java

```
//import not included
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GridView grid;

String[] web = {
        "Google",
        "Github",
        "Instagram",
        "Facebook",


} ;
int[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher

};
private LayoutParams layoutParams;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);

            grid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new   AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       grid.setItemChecked(position, true);
                  View tv=(View) grid.getChildAt(position);
                  tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    return false;
                }


            });
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }); 
}
}
```

CustomGrid.java

```
    //import not included
    public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] web;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            EditText textView = (EditText) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
         //   Button b1=(Button)grid.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            textView.setText(web[position]);


            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.. thanks in advance..

Comment: "Edit Text set" what does that mean ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding these lines in your `EditText`

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: I tried using this but I want edit text to be editable.Can you suggest something else.?

Comment: edit text will be editable but focus that does not contain focus which allow accessing onItemClick.

Answer (score 0):

So finally solved the problem.
I used gesturelistener and detected motion.
Thank You.